# Getting started with Jackrabbit WebDav Servlet

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets, jackrabbit

First of all let me say that I'm new to Java EE development. My knowledge stops at creating a simple helloworld servelt in Eclipse and test it in Tomcat 6.

I now need to create a WebDav servlet. I came to Jackrabbit and searched around for tutorials but I couldn't find any information that is suitable for my current knowledge level.

The only indications I could find is to create a class which extends the AbstractWebdavServlet, then implement the other classes.

So I created a dinamic web project in eclipse, I added the jackrabbit-webdav-2.4.3.jar dependency and created a class which looks like this

```
import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.DavLocatorFactory;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.DavResource;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.DavResourceFactory;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.DavSessionProvider;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.WebdavRequest;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.server.AbstractWebdavServlet;


public class testDAV extends AbstractWebdavServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public DavSessionProvider getDavSessionProvider() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DavLocatorFactory getLocatorFactory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DavResourceFactory getResourceFactory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isPreconditionValid(WebdavRequest arg0, DavResource arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDavSessionProvider(DavSessionProvider arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setLocatorFactory(DavLocatorFactory arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setResourceFactory(DavResourceFactory arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

then I am stuck here.
Can someone tell me a good beginner-level tutorial on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a WebDAV servlet, without the underlying content storage features of Jackrabbit, that's probably not the best choice. Other java libraries like http://milton.io/ provide just the WebDAV plumbing parts and will be easier to adapt to specific needs.

That being said, Jackrabbit is a great tool if you also need content storage, and in that case you shouldn't need to write any code to use its WebDAV servlet, which is out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at our Webdav servlet wich extends Apache jackrabbit own to add some features about security (configuring the realm and using digest auth).
https://github.com/Silverpeas/Silverpeas-Core/blob/master/web-core/src/main/java/com/silverpeas/jcrutil/servlets/SimpleDigestWebdavServlet.java